# Is it possible to make Flutter 60FPS smooth, no matter how janky and slow my app currently is, using general-purpose and easy-to-use existing tools?

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, optimization

I have a Flutter app which is becoming more and more janky as time goes by and more features are added. Therefore, is there some utility to make it as smooth as 60FPS?

I know there are some official guides here: https://docs.flutter.dev/perf. However, I have tried to optimize and it is still slow. You know, some things just cannot be fast enough, such as long text, dynamic layout, necessary synchronous computations, etc. Especially when entering a new page or scrolling down a ListView. In addition, I have to use brainpower to find out what is slow and optimize when new features are added, so I hope there is some fully automatic thing which I can drop-in replace and forget it and it just works forever.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** I wrote this package and this is a Q&A style StackOverflow answer.

Yes, I have made it: https://github.com/fzyzcjy/flutter_smooth.

No matter how heavy the tree is to build/layout, it will run at (roughly) full FPS, feel smooth, has zero uncomfortable janks, with neglitable overhead. (I have made some benchmark reports [here](https://fzyzcjy.github.io/flutter_smooth/benchmark))

As for usage, for common scenarios, add 6 characters ("Smooth") - ListView becomes SmoothListView, MaterialPageRoute becomes SmoothMaterialPageRoute. For complex cases, use SmoothBuilder(builder: ...) and put whatever you want to be smooth inside the builder.

Roughly speaking about the implementation, it is done by submitting extra frames to the rasterizer every ~16ms, without disturbing all existing code. Therefore, the existing app code will almost not even know the existence of this package.

Comment: Thanks for created it, it will be a wonderful package to use!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check how do you use widgets, unnecessary rebuilds, some heavy operations when the widget is creating o rebuilding   and it’s recommended to use the performance profiler in the devtools.

Comment: Totally agree, https://docs.flutter.dev/perf has told about that as well. The problem is that sometimes it is still janky after applying all those.

Comment: I am disagree, I work in some projects with performance issues and I can fix it

Comment: You can share some piece of code with performance issues to help you

Comment: Sure, *some* projects are able to be fixed performance issues, but not *all*. The "scenario" section may be related: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FuNcBvAPghUyjeqQCOYxSt6lGDAQ1YxsNlOvrUx0Gko/edit#